# Why the duplicated cloth object does not fall?

Tags: animation, objects, physics, cloth-simulation

I duplicated the two cloth objects from the cloth object that I've already adjust the physics and played it back in the timeline. When I do this, the original object falls, but the two duplicated objects stay around the pivot point position and curl up into a ball on the spot. Please give me advise to solve this problem if you know what is causing this.

[image]

---

PS - The third attempt somehow worked. In the end, I do not know the cause of this problem. I'll add a screenshot here.
[image]

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Comment: sorry, I can not provide the file. But if anyone have any idea where the cause might be,  I will share the information and screenshots of the area. So please let me know.

Comment: I just tried the third copy. This time, it fell just like the original object. I still don't know why the first two didn't work, but I can move on for now.